# Does game time increase while paused in God of War?

Tags: achievements, god-of-war

In the God of War collection for PS3, the *Speed of Jason McDonald* trophy is awarded for beating the original God of War in under 5 hours.

Does time spent on the pause screen or upgrade menu count as time played in the original God of War?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this guide](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/god-of-war/trophy/11558-Speed-of-Jason-McDonald.html), pausing it will not count as time, but the upgrade menu will.

> - Cutscenes cannot be skipped but they do not add to the time
> - **Pausing the game will pause the timer, going into the upgrade screen, however, will not**
> - If you mess up, restart from the last checkpoint and the time will reset back to where it was before
> - Avoid all unnecessary fights, only fight when you have to
> - The fastest way to move in the game is do roll with the  then immediately press  (Hermes Rush). This requires one upgrade into your blades first.
> - In the Vita version, pressing the  button and bringing up the XMB will stop the timer so you can take stock of the situation and plan your next move (credit to Blaze Naruto Shippuden for this tip).
> - Also in the Vita version, you have to press the icon of the Hermes Rush so it's  + quickly tap the Hermes Rush Icon on the touchscreen (credit to Blaze Naruto Shippuden for this tip).

I wish you the best of luck in obtaining the trophy!

Cheers!